# Set up TeamCity status visualizer

Tags: teamcity

I'd like to show TC build statuses on a big TV screen, however the default TeamCity main page contains too many details, and I'd like to show only basic info and colorise e.g. background to red when build status is marked as failed. Do you know any nice TC visualizers? I've tried to se greasemonkey and script from http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/92241, but I'm getting jquery error - the script itself is a bit outdated.

Comment: I've no idea why this question was downvoted, it's a good question so the the least I could do was upvote it :-)

Answer (score 12):

There are several TeamCity plugins for big screen visualisation. Different plugins (or standalone apps) have different dependencies (because of programming language), and they all seem to display slightly different information, so you'll want to take a look at the screenshots and start with one that shows what you want.

<strike>See the [Notification/Visualizers section of the TeamCity Plugins page](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/TeamCity+Plugins#TeamCityPlugins-Notification%2FVisualizers) for the list.</strike>

JetBrains is now maintaining the list in their [plugin repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/category/95-notification-visualizers/teamcity).

Comment: There is also a code sample / example here
http://markswanderingthoughts.nl/post/40012275522/visually-attractive-teamcity-ci-dashboard

Comment: Most of them are abandoned and don't work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

There are several TeamCity dashboard plugins for Chrome that can be used as big screen visualisation.

- [BuildReactor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buildreactor/agfdekbncfakhgofmaacjfkpbhjhpjmp)
- [TeamCity Status Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/teamcity-status-monitor/ojkkaphfgjpbckihnbbminnoenhndeje)